# Why replace() doesn't work in my Python function? in one liner

Tags: python

I am trying to solve the already asked question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56218919/why-replace-doesnt-work-in-my-python-function#56218987) with one liner. But not getting expected.

```
d={'Old': 'New', 'old': 'new'}
strr='Old, not old'
```

Attempt

```
[ strr.replace(k,v) for k,v in d.items() if k in strr] 
Out[19]: ['New, not old', 'Old, not new']
```

Expected

```
New, not new
```

Comment: it works, and does what you wrote. the issue is, you're only replacing using 1 key,value pair at a time.

Answer (score 5):

Because you are using a [list generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) that is constructing a list of strings where each string contains only one replace from the dictionary. Just use ordinary loops to replace everything word-by-word:

```
d={'Old': 'New', 'old': 'new'}
strr='Old, not old'

for k, v in d.items():
    strr = strr.replace(k, v)

strr
```

will return:

`'New, not new'`

Comment: is it not possible in one liner ?

Comment: Well, technically you can write `for k, v in d.items(): strr = strr.replace(k, v)` in one line. But it is bad code and you should avoid this. It is ok to have several lines even for simple task, especially if it improves code readability.